# Python including C code

Tags: python, include

We are developing software in Python, but two of our team know only C/C++. My question is, how can we make plugins or is it possible to include dll in Python and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html

http://docs.python.org/extending/

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C

http://wiki.cacr.caltech.edu/danse/index.php/Writing_C_extensions_for_Python

Comment: Is it possible to use matlab and java?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you already have existing C/C++ libraries you want to integrate into Python, it's a waste of time. Toss a copy of [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) on their desks and tell them to take a few days to learn it.